# Find an Item in an array and add a value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays , I want to find the item in Arr1 with Arr2 Keys and map the value of arr2 to arr1 if not found value should be 0.

```
const Arr1=['A','B','C']
const Arr2=[{key:'a',val:100},{key:'c',val:100}]
```

Expected Result:

```
const Arr3=[{key:'a',val:100},{key:'b',val:0},{key:'c',val:100}]
```

Comment: okay, so what have you done so far apart from getting the requirement?

Comment: What do you mean by _"map the value of arr2 to arr1 if not found value should be 0."_?

Comment: please follow the edited one

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use **[`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** and **[`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)** like this:

```js
const Arr1=['A','B','C']
const Arr2=[{key:'a',val:100},{key:'c',val:100}]

const Arr3 = Arr1.map(c => {
  const exists = Arr2.find(b => b.key === c.toLowerCase());
  return exists || { key: c.toLowerCase(), val: 0 };
})

console.log(Arr3)
```

Or using **[`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)** like this:

```js
const Arr1=['A','B','C']
const Arr2=[{key:'a',val:100},{key:'c',val:100}]

const Arr3 = Arr1.reduce((r, a) => {
  const exists = Arr2.find(b => b.key === a.toLowerCase());
  const item = exists || { key: a.toLowerCase(), val: 0 }
  return r.concat(item)
},[])

console.log(Arr3)
```

Comment: concat creates a new array.

Comment: And that's a problem because..?

Comment: That's not a problem, its a good answer but push would be better if creating a new array each time is not a need?

Comment: If we use `push`, then we need to write another line to return the accumulator. `r.push(item); return r`. But `concat` returns the merged array and can be returned in one go

Comment: is there any way to make the arr3 with the contents of arr1 as it is instead of making everything in lowercae

Comment: @ReNinja I don't understand the question. You want to update `Arr1` instead of creating a new array?

Comment: You can just assign like this `Arr1` = `Arr1.reduce((r, a) => {....})`. If you don't want to reassign, then use `Arr1.forEach((c, index) =>{  // do "Arr1[index] = item" with same calculation as reduce })`

Answer (score 1):

In context to you previous question you can still return a value if you want and convert keys to lowercase before compare.

```
const Arr1=['a','b','c']
var Arr2=[{key:'a',val:100},{key:'c',val:100}]

Arr2.map(val => {
 if(Arr1.indexOf(val.key) >= 0 )
  val.val = val
 else
  val =  0
})
```